NestJs Prisma FindMany Return
findMany return the corps of my function
see picture


My result is wrong why for FindMany but in FindUnique and Post the result is Ok?
any idea to resolve this issue ?
thanks for All.

Don't post images:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Please provide some code,  create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
